# Is noexcept useless when not throwing is zero-cost?

Tags: c++, exception, compilation, noexcept

Is the `noexcept` specifier useless if your implementation has a zero-cost (if nothing is thrown) exception model? What is an example where lacking `noexcept` has a consequence?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727975/when-should-one-explicitly-attribute-noexcept

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is the `noexcept` specifier useless if your implementation has a zero-cost (if nothing is thrown) exception model?

No, `noexcept` would be useful even if exceptions had no performance impact at all.

One example is that `noexcept` can signal which algorithm can be used. For example algorithms that use [`std::move_if_noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept) or many of the standard [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) could behave differently depending on the presence of `noexcept`.

This can have a significant impact for common features like `std::vector` which will be much slower if you elements' move constructor isn't `noexcept`. `std::vector` will copy all elements when reallocating instead of moving them if the move constructor is not `noexcept` to preserve the strong exception guarantee.

Comment: Why would one prefer to copy if both can throw?

Comment: @lajoh90686 If you start moving elements and one throws it isn't possible to undo the changes. You have two arrays each containing a portion of the elements and you can't be sure moving them back will work (because evidently moving can fail). If you start copying elements and one throws you can just throw away the new partially copied array and the old data is preserved.

Comment: @lajoh90686 pretty much anytime you want to ensure the strong exception guarantee